# Upload a HTML page to server along with the referenced images using Java

Tags: java, html, servlets, file-upload, webserver

I am working on a code, that requires uploading of any kind of document from client's machine to the server, and extracting images out of it. For almost all docs Tika is helpful, but in case of an html page, the images are referenced to the local machine's path. So how do I upload the html page along with the images it contains?
I'm using Java Servlets and JSP as platform.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible to solve server-side, you have to implement a client-side (Javascript? Java applet? Flash (yuck!)?) solution. The HTML document is just a text, it does not contain the images - it just references them. So you have to parse the document, get the images, upload them independently, and then - server-side - process the document and adjust the image references (the values of `src` attributes).

Pretty complex, isn't it?

Comment: Hey @Jozef, got what you are saying and was working on something like that only but parsing the document, uploading images independently works only when the src tags contains the Absolute path of the referenced image. If the path turns out to be relative, then?

Comment: @Nidhijain Well, then you have to convert it to absolute. You must know (or find out), where the HTML document is located on the client's filesystem, and convert the relative paths accordingly.

Comment: And it has to be done on the client side? No way, we can bring this up at server?

Comment: Yes, it must be done client-side - you have to find out, where are the images, and this can be done only client-side. Then, server-side, you can adjust the `src` parameters of `img` tags in the processed HTML document, but first you have to upload the images and store them on the server (and don't forget to make them accessible, too).